# Jenkins finishing with Finished: SUCCESS even though Python exiting with sys.exit(-1)

Tags: python, jenkins

Python code:

```
print "Initiating myPy..."
...
try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "d:", ["dolphins="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print '\tUsage: python myPy.py -d <foo>'
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Server response:

> Initiating myPy...
>
> ```
>    Usage: python myPy.py -d <foo>
> ```
>
> Finished: SUCCESS

I was under the impression from several sources that any nonzero system exit code was supposed to result in a build failure. Why is this not happening in my case? Does it have something to do with a build configuration setting?

Comment: Just checking first - does your python script get called directly, or within a wrapper script? That is, will the return code from python reach Jenkins?

Comment: Good question. At the moment it is invoked like so in the bash build script: _python myPy.py -d $DolphinVar_

So I'm not sure if Jenkins sees it.

Comment: EDIT: I was missing the -e bash blag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It seems like you are running the python script from a bash script, what flags jenkins use when it runs the bash script? `/bin/sh sh133331232.sh -xe`? the -e flag denotes exit on fail, is it there?
2. Try adding `exit $?` after the python script runs.

Comment: You're a genius! I was missing the -e flag! Thank you!